# Adding a column with two-step calculations to an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio for this task. I'm a bit raw at SQL and very confused on how to get this done. The data is football data, solo refers to solo tackles. Here's where i'm at first, i've created my calculated field:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.player, A.year, A.Solo, A.Total, A.Team, C.SoloTotal, 
CAST(A.Solo AS Decimal) / NULLIF(CAST(C.SoloTotal AS Decimal),0) * 100 
AS SoloDR
FROM [Football].[dbo].[WRK_CFBDef] A,
   (
    SELECT A.YearTeam, SUM(A.Solo) AS SoloTotal
    FROM [Football].[dbo].[WRK_CFBDef] A
    GROUP By A.YearTeam
    ) C
```

The first field i created is an addition of all values in A.Solo grouped by an index field of YearTeam, called SoloTotal in the subquery. Then in the main query, it takes that field and divides the original individual value of A.Solo by the grouped sum of C.SoloTotal to get the percentage of Solo tackles each individual player had in context of their team that year as SoloDR.

What i want to do is have that number permanently added to the table in its own column beside the player as SoloDR.

I've tried something like this but it's not working and i'm certain its probably not even the right path.

```
Alter Table [football].[dbo].[Test]
ADD COLUMN SoloDR AS 
(SELECT C.SoloDR
FROM [Football].[dbo].[WRK_CFBDef] A
    (
    SELECT SUM(A.Solo) AS SoloTotal
    FROM [Football].[dbo].[WRK_CFBDef] A
    ) C )
```

What would the code i'm looking for look like here?

Comment: In sql server, the add column syntax does not include the word column.

Answer (score 0):

This requires at least two steps.

Step 1 is to add the column to the table. Note that if you want to add a non-nullable column to a table that already contains data, you will also need to create a DEFAULT, unless the column is an IDENTITY or a TIMESTAMP.

Here is the basic syntax to add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE [Football].[dbo].[WRK_CFBDef]
    ADD [SoloDR] INT NULL
```

[ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql)

Step 2 is to UPDATE the existing table, setting the value of SoloDR as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a computed column due to the GROUP BY.

You shouldn't add the column to the table, since you're storing duplicate data.

You shouldn't rely on StackOverflow to provide pure answers to the (home)work you should be doing, but we can give a hint:
[Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) with a join to a derived table, which you already had, will handle this accurately, if slowly.